# Java program that kills itself on new instance

Tags: java, process, ipc

So I am trying to have a Java program that starts running when the main method is invoked and stops running when the **same** main method is invoked (from another process). So the goal is to kill the first process with the second process, and then kill itself.

What I have tried are the following:

1. `taskkill` for Windows and `kill` for Unix.

   This is the simplest way to do achieve the goal. But the process in Windows is always `javaw.exe` and calling `taskkill` would terminate other JVMs.
2. `ServerSocket` or `DatagramSocket`, to tell the first process to kill itself.

   This works as well but I feel like this is just a waste for such a simple job.
3. File locks

   The problem is that the permission of creating a file is not always granted (for whatever reason someone decides to use the program in read-only folders).

I think I might just missed something obvious. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve restart?

Comment: @ShineedBasheer No. I am trying to terminates both the running process and the newly spawned process.

Comment: The only safe way is using some sort of communication via files. I would use a special directory in the temp directory as every process should have write permissions here.